# In CakePHP, how do I add a script *once only* to my layout now that View->addScript() is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

In CakePHP 2.1:

What's the best way to add a snippet of Javascript **once only** to my layout (ie. a block) now that 

`View->addScript()` is [deprecated](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/view#method-ViewaddScript)?

**EDIT:**

`$this->Html->script()` (linking to a JS file) seems to keep track of duplicate scripts, 
but `$this->Html->scriptBlock()` (inline JS) does not. :-(

Comment: I don't use CakePHP but [this section in the CakePHP documentation about blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files) may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->Html->script('scriptname');
```

And make sure your script is in the js folder in the webroot

Comment: Thanks Chris. You're right... `$this->Html->script()` (linking to a JS file) does seem to keep track of duplicate scripts, but unfortunately `$this->Html->scriptBlock()` (inline JS) does not. I'm actually in need of the second option.  Hmm...

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things that you could do:

**1. Look for a declared variable (dirty workaround)**

If you really want the code to be in `$this->Html->scriptBlock()`, you can defined/check a global variable, to see if the code has already been defined. For example:

```
if (!DEFINED('someVarName')) {
    // define the variable from now on
    DEFINE('someVarName', true);
    // add your block
    $this->Html->scriptBlock(...);
}
```

---

**2. Create custom JS route and files (the Cake way)**

The best thing to do is create an actual JS file for your view that can be included with `$this->Html->script()`, but if you want to integrate PHP code into your JS, it gets annoying. Cake has an awesome method for creating view-specific JS scripts that they don't seem to talk about much (and I can't figure out why).

Just add this to your `Config/routes.php` file:

```
Router::parseExtensions('js');
```

That makes Cake automatically look for a JS View for your controller action, if you just add ".js" to the end of your URL.  For example:

`$this->Html->script('/users/profile.js')` looks for `View/Users/js/profile.ctp`

Then, it serves it up with the JS layout.  This is awesome, because you'll still have access to all of the variables and data that were set in your Controller.

Now... just one problem.  The default JS layout wraps the contents in a  tag. This is no good if we're trying to include our script externally, like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/users/profile.js"></script>`.

I don't really have much use for the JS layout in this fashion, but it's possible that I might at some point, so I just edited the layout file to make it adaptable:

```
// app/View/Layouts/js/default.ctp
<? 
if (isset($this->request->params['ext']) && $this->request->params['ext']=='js') {
    echo $this->fetch('content'); 
} else {
?>
    <? echo $scripts_for_layout; ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"><?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?></script>
<? } ?>
```

---

More info (though, not much more) at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions